# Complex js obfuscator

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I need a complex js obfuscator so that the js file won't be easy to reverse with a public tool like http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Just note that anyone who is determined enough will still be able to read your code regardless of how obfuscated it is. It will only slow them down.

Comment: A quick Google search gives lots of suggestions.  Which obfuscators have you tried, and in what ways are they insufficient for your needs?

Comment: i just want not to work with that online converters like the one i gave. May be something that is done in two steps so it can't be reversed straight forward in one step.

Comment: Run the code through two obfuscators?  =]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try [jscrambler.com](http://jscrambler.com/). It's the only one I know that could help you. [Check what it does.](http://jscrambler.com/index/javascript_obfuscator_features)

Answer (score 2):

You can shrink variable names when you use Dean Edward's packer. While this *can* be reversed, it does leave you with pretty unreadable code as the variables aren't easily identifiable.

http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

Comment: Note that even Dean does not call his tool an obfuscator, but compressor.

Comment: It takes 2 seconds to make the code perfectly readable :) This tool unpacks code packed by Dean Edwards packer and formats it nicely too: http://jsbeautifier.org

Comment: yes I need something that can't be reversed so easy with jsbeautifier.org? some custom obfuscation is also welcome. It doesn't matter if the code can not be reversed after that!

Answer (score 0):

Use Packer algo http://dean.edwards.name/packer/

do check the options 'Base62 encode' and 'shrink variables'. This will obfuscate the code to a certain limit but still, as @musicfreak said, anyone who is determined can still make out the code.

Answer (score 0):

Google Closure Compiler.

http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/

I use it on advanced.  Read the docs about exporting public methods etc. 
http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3.html

It rocks.

Comment: From personal experience, it doesn't obfuscate code *that* much.

Comment: Did you use it on advanced?  Can you provide an example of it on advanced and "not obfusticating code that much"?  Would love to see.

Comment: Closure compiler only optimizes really. Also the advanced mode breaks the code easily if you are not careful. It requires some head work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a JavaScript library, consider Dojo Toolkit which is compatible (after minor modifications) with the Closure Compiler's Advanced mode compilation.

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t

Code compiled with Closure Advanced mode is almost impossible to reverse-engineer, even passing through a beautifier, as the *entire* code base (includinhg the library) is obfuscated.  It is also 25% small on average.

JavaScript code that is merely minified (YUI Compressor, Uglify etc.) is easy to reverse-engineer after passing through a beautifier.